# How to get name or identifier for a UIView component

Tags: objective-c, uiview, appdelegate

In the below code I want to have any identifier to the -firstView- as shown below in the code.
I attempted the following:

```
//NSLog(@"_[uiviews[0] _description] = %@" , [uiviews[0] _description]);
  //NSLog(@"[uiviews[0] nameLabel] = %@" , [uiviews[0] nameLabel]);
    //NSLog(@"[uiviews[0] textLabel]= %@" , [[uiviews[0] textLabel].text);
 NSString *r = [uiviews[0] textLabel].text;
    NSLog(@"[uiviews[0] textLabel]= %@", r);a
```

But, on activating any of them, the App crashes. Would you please let me know how to have access to the name or any string identifies that UIView.

**code**

```
        UIView *firstView = uiviews[0];
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966532/unique-identifier-of-an-uiview-object/28667421 ? Why do you really need it? Seems like a bad idea. Why not testing if `[firstView isOfClass:[UILabel class]]` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Use `UIView.tag` to identify views in your app:

```
UIView* anotherView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
anotherView.tag = 100;
[view addSubview:anotherView];
UIView* anotherViewAgain = [view viewWithTag:100];
NSLog(@"anotherView and anotherViewAgain are %@the same objects", anotherView == anotherViewAgain ? @"" : @"not "); // prints "anotherView and anotherViewAgain are the same objects"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can give a try with accessibilityIdentifier of UIView. 
uiview tag, is not the best idea (or extend it with enum Int raw value).

with accessibilityIdentifier you can do a lot more logic in nice way.